# replacing part of a string but the part is very long

Tags: python, string

I was wondering how I could replace a part of a string where the part is two character very far away and whats in the middle doesnt matter. An exemple will better explain it:

```
"1.........\n1.........\n2........."
```

or as its visual output in the text file:

```
1.........
1.........
2.........
```

if for exemple I want to change that if there is a "1" on top of another "1", they both change to "2":

```
1.........
1.........
2......... (or "1.........\n1.........\n2.........")

into

2.........
2.........
2......... (or "2.........\n2.........\n2.........")
```

how would I do that? I know how to do it vertically with re.sub

```
re.sub("11", "22", name_of_string)
```

but now I want to do it vertically or another word, with 10 unspecified character between each "1".
if I didnt explain well enough to be understood let me know and I will try to be more clear, thanks for taking the time of answering

Comment: Your feeling was right: try to be more clear. See [mcve]. Also specify what characters you are using. Are those dots supposed to be whitespace?

Comment: Do you even need to replace the characters in the allocated string? If your goal is just to output (even if not), the most efficient solution is probably to iterate over the lines, parse the number, decide which number to put before the rest of the line and `yield` that. If you need the whole string back, just `"\n".join()` the individual lines.

Comment: no the dot arent whitespace, they are unspecified character, (they shouldnt matter whatever they are).  And yeah I need to replace the character in the allocated string since the length of the string is something that needs to stay the same